# Iterate Pandas Chunks through preprocessing/cleaning before concatenating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Good day Python/Pandas Gurus:

I deal with memory issues while performing data analysis on my local machine. I typically deal with data in the shape of (15000000+, 50+). I typically chunk the data into chunksize=1000000 in pd.read_csv(), and this always works great for me.

I am wondering how I can iterate each chunk through my entire data cleaning/preprocessing section, so that I do not have to run the entire data frame through this section of code. I find I hit system limitations and run out of memory.

I want to read the pandas chunks, iterate each through a function or just a series of steps that renames columns, filters the data frame, and assign data types. Once this preprocessing is complete for all chunks, I would like the now processed chunks to then be concatenated together, creating the completed data frame.

```
df_chunks = pandas.read_csv("File.path", chunksize=10000)

for chunks in df_chunks:
   Task 1: Rename Columns
   Task 2: Filter(s)
   Task 3: Assign data types to non-object fields

processed_df = pd.concat(df_chunks)
```

Here is a samples of code that I run the entire Data Frame through for preprocessing, but hit system limitations for the volume of data that I have:

```
billing_docs_clean.columns = ['BillingDocument', 'BillingDocumentItem', 'BillingDocumentType', 'BillingCategory', 'DocumentCategory',
                'DocumentCurrency', 'SalesOrganization', 'DistributionChannel', 'PricingProcedure',
                'DocumentConditionNumber', 'ShippingConditions', 'BillingDate', 'CustomerGroup', 'Incoterms',
                'PostingStatus', 'PaymentTerms', 'DestinationCountry', 'Region', 'CreatedBy', 'CreationTime',
                'SoldtoNumber', 'Curr1', 'Divison', 'Curr2', 'ExchangeRate', 'BilledQuantitySUn', 'SalesUnits',
                'Numerator', 'Denominator', 'BilledQuantityBUn', 'BaseUnits', 'RequiredQuantity', 'BUn1', 'ExchangeRate2',
                'ItemNetValue', 'Curr3', 'ReferenceDocument', 'ReferenceDocumentItem', 'ReferencyDocumentCategory',
                'SalesDocument', 'SalesDocumentItem', 'Material', 'MaterialDescription', 'MaterialGroup',
                'SalesDocumentItemCategory', 'SalesProductHierarchy', 'ShippingPoint', 'Plant', 'PlantRegion',
                'SalesGroup', 'SalesOffice', 'Returns', 'Cost', 'Curr4', 'GrossValue', 'Curr5', 'NetValue', 'Curr6',
                'CashDiscount', 'Curr7', 'FreightCharges', 'Curr8', 'Rebate', 'Curr9', 'OVCFreight', 'Curr10', 'ProfitCenter',
                'CreditPrice', 'Curr11', 'SDDocumentCategory']

# Filter data to obtain US, Canada, and Mexico industrial sales for IFS Profit Center
billing_docs_clean = billing_docs_clean[
    (billing_docs_clean['DistributionChannel'] == '02') & 
    (billing_docs_clean['ProfitCenter'].str.startswith('00001', na=False)) &  
    (billing_docs_clean['ReferenceDocumentItem'].astype(float) < 900000) &   
    (billing_docs_clean['PostingStatus']=='C') &  
    (billing_docs_clean['PricingProcedure'] != 'ZEZEFD') & 
    (billing_docs_clean['SalesDocumentItemCategory'] != 'TANN')]


# Correct Field Formats and data types
Date_Fields_billing_docs_clean = ['BillingDate']
for datefields in Date_Fields_billing_docs_clean:
    billing_docs_clean[datefields] = pd.to_datetime(billing_docs_clean[datefields])

Trim_Zeros_billing_docs_clean = ['BillingDocument', 'BillingDocumentItem', 'ProfitCenter', 'Material', 'ReferenceDocument',
                      'ReferenceDocumentItem', 'SalesDocument', 'SalesDocumentItem']
for TrimFields in Trim_Zeros_billing_docs_clean:
    billing_docs_clean[TrimFields] = billing_docs_clean[TrimFields].str.lstrip('0')

Numeric_Fields_billing_docs_clean = ['ExchangeRate', 'BilledQuantitySUn', 'Numerator', 'Denominator', 'BilledQuantityBUn',
                          'RequiredQuantity', 'ExchangeRate2', 'ItemNetValue', 'Cost', 'GrossValue', 'NetValue',
                          'CashDiscount', 'FreightCharges', 'Rebate', 'OVCFreight', 'CreditPrice']
for NumericFields in Numeric_Fields_billing_docs_clean:
    billing_docs_clean[NumericFields] = billing_docs_clean[NumericFields].astype('str').str.replace(',','').astype(float)
```

I am still relatively new with python coding for data analytics, but eager to learn! So I appreciate any and all explanations or any other recommendations for the code in this post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Task 1: Rename Columns

For this you can harness [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) optional arguments `header` and `names`. Consider following simple example, let `file.csv` content be

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

then

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=0,names=["X","Y","Z"])
print(df)
```

output

```
   X  Y  Z
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```